# Getting the date for the users current time zone?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

When using NSDate to get today's date, I seem to be getting a date that is ahead in time. For example, today is February 19 but NSDate is giving me February 20?

What can I do to get the proper date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm using `NSDate *today = [NSDate date];` to get todays date but the problem is that it's not in my current time zone.

This sentence doesn't make sense. An `NSDate` object represents a single point in time, regardless of time zone. NSDate does not even have a sense of time zones.

To output a date as a string, always create an instance of `NSDateFormatter` and call its `stringFromDate:` method. By default, `NSDateFormatter` uses the current user's time zone.